# Disable serial console on Ubuntu Snappy

Tags: ubuntu-core, raspberrypi, serial-port

I would like to know is there any method to disable serial console on Snappy? I am using raspberry pi build. I need this because I have to use /dev/ttyAMA0 to communicate with hardware module.

Comment: Why not simply connect raspberry to your home router over ethernet , ssh into it to work there ? That way `/dev/ttyAMA0` should be available for the module.  Aside from that, there should be new device file dynamically allocated if `/dev/ttyAMA0` is in use , named `/dev/ttyAMA1`.

Comment: No, i have a hardware module that need to plug into UART on GPIO, so need to gain access to /dev/ttyAMA0

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to disable the systemd service serial-getty@ from /lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service

This is what trigger the other service leading to /dev/tty<…> creation for serial communication.

We don't have a full solution yet on snappy ubuntu core side, but you probably can hack around a systemd service in /etc/systemd/system/ doing this masking until we get proper support in the plateforme itself.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on BeagleBone w/ Snappy, but would need to be run after a reboot:

```
% sudo service serial-getty@ttyO0 stop
```

Also, according to [this article](http://lavalink.com/2012/04/more-on-raspberry-pi-serial-ports/) there's at least one additional serial port available on the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked this on Ubuntu Snappy, however on Ubuntu Server the cmdline.txt is loaded from /boot/firmware instead of just /boot

Remove the serial port terminal by editing this file and removing `console=serial0,115200`, save and reboot.

If you need to enable the serial port itself, you can put `enable_uart=1` into /boot/firmware/usercfg.txt and reboot.

You can edit these files using `nano` and you will need to execute it using root permissions with `sudo` e.g.:

`sudo nano /boot/firmware/usercfg.txt`

`sudo nano /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt`

Press Ctrl + X to exit Nano, it will ask you to confirm your changes, type in `y` and press enter.